# What drawbacks are there to this method of using a single web server for 3 different sites?

Tags: php, .htaccess, twitter-bootstrap, subdomain, nearlyfreespeech

I'm using nearlyfreespeech.net as a web host, and I got tired of having to manage 3 sites for 3 subdomains on my website, so I was looking into how to serve all 3 from one site.

Each site is a shortname.nfshost.com domain, and can have an alias for a subdomain or domain. For example.com and sub.example.com, I would normally make two sites, examplewww and examplesub (I try to make the short names clear), and set www.example.com and example.com as aliases to examplewww, and sub.example.com as alias to examplesub, then point cname DNS record for the names to shortname.nfshost.com.

My solution was to make one site as PHP (since they charge more for PHP than for static), with the following:

```
<?php $site = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  if ($site == 'example.com') {
    include('www.example.com.php'); # If domain is example.com, serve that page
  } elseif ($site == 'sub.example.com') {
    include('sub.example.com.php'); if domain is sub.example.com, serve that page instead
  } elseif ($site == 'www.example.com') {
    header('Location: http://example.com'); redirects www to no-www
  } else {
    header('Location: http://example.com'); don't let browser go to examplewww.nfshost.com
} ?>
```

The 2 included PHP files are bootstrap-themed, with CDN links for the CSS/images (bootstrap cdn, my own static site that I call a CDN (which has a complicated htaccess redirect and folders separated by site, so each site I manage can have their own images)), and besides the 404 error page (also bootstrap), these are the only files on the server (index, sub.example.com include, www.example.com include, 404).

I am able to have PHP code run within the included PHP files without a problem, and even have them include other files. The output looks normal (HTML, looks valid).

I was able to use one CMS platform, after a few glitches (setting the base_url) by including the CMS's index (as index2.php), and I sort-of got a thing working where I can deny directories if the site doesn't match (sub.example.com/folder I can return 404 if coming from www.example.com).

**Question:** are there any problems with this? I feel like I'm making it overly complicated, I don't know PHP very well, and I don't know if there's a problem with this that I can't think of.

I also think that if this solution was this easy, I would have seen it somewhere in my many Google searches, which makes me think it's not that good of a solution. Is there any reason not to make it this complicated?

I'm not worried about downtime, or anything like that. Besides my own visits, my site gets maybe 3 people visit a month, according to Google Analytics, and it's mostly contact info (but I have a few php scripts to show information, so I'd need to have php for all 3 subdomains, which gets to be a little more expensive with nearlyfreespeech).

Comment: If you have three separate sites, I'd manage them as three separate sites. Why are you getting tired of managing all three? It seems to me that it is simpler to split them up - when you deploy a new version of one, you have a lot less that can go wrong. Perhaps you could look into a simple automated deployment approach, so that pushing new versions is zero hassle?

Comment: Also, if you are making decisions about server configuration based on cost, maybe a VPS would be a good idea? You can then have what you want for a fixed cost, and for your purposes you can probably get a suitable box for around 50USD per annum. Check LowEndBox if that's of interest.

Comment: @halfer: Like I said, my sites are personal (contact, and a family site). So at the moment, there's really only 3 single pages that need to be displayed.

Comment: @halfer (pressed enter too soon) in addition, nearlyfreespeech has very cheap billing. I bought a $20 account (money that sites take out of for storage and usage billing) in September '13, and so far, with 3-4 sites each dynamic php (their more expensive options), I've used up $3.60. I've yet to see a VPS that's cheaper than this. 

And if I use one site with nearlyfreespeech, it's even cheaper, since there's a daily charge (I hope the added bandwidth evens out for that, since it's stochastic billing)
Thanks for the LowEndBox mention though, that looks interesting. Just not necessary for me.

Comment: Right, if you can collapse them down to one codebase/repo, then sure, run it from one vhost and set up several server aliases. Doesn't seem to complicated to me.

Comment: @halfer I went ahead and paid for a vps from that site you mentioned! Just wanted to say thanks.

Comment: Ah, no problem, glad that sorted it for you!